# Best way to set a common variable between projects in PHP?

Tags: php, organization, code-organization, project-organization

I have several projects on my host. They have many similarities and I want them to use common node_modules. My folder structure looks something like this:

```
_CONFIG.php
node_modules/
project1/
    index.php
project2/
    index.php
project3/
    index.php
```

In all my index.php files, I `require_once '../_CONFIG.php'` where I've set:

```
$node_modules = '../node_modules/';
```

Then in each project, when I need to use a Node module, I have:

```
<script src="<?= $node_modules; ?>jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

I do this because I might need to change the path of node_modules. If everything is hardcoded, I'd have a rough time. Let's say I install upgraded node_modules and I want to have a backup. I want to be able to quickly switch between the old and new modules, in case some of the new ones are incompatible with one of my projects.

I have other common things between the projects that I want to be easily configurable via the _CONFIG.php file.

### Question

I know that polluting the global scope is not a great thing and that's exactly what I'm doing. Is there a better way to do this? In the same time, I don't want to do a ton of stuff just to output a string in a script tag's `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining constants? It's quite useful for defining global options, and you do not pollute the global scope at all.

```
define('NODE_MODULES_DIR', '../node_modules/');
```

and then later use it there:

```
<script src="<?= NODE_MODULES_DIR ?>jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not aware of a "better" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping configuration outside of your code is the way to go. You put all your connection strings, pwds etc in a config file as suggested by [The Twelve-Factor App](https://www.12factor.net/config).

Instead of using global variables, you could add one level of indirection by using a wrapper function that returns values based on a given key-string.

[phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) provides these capabilities nicely.